# Installing Windows 7 on Kali Linux

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, windows-installation, kali-linux

When I recently installed Kali Linux on my Windows 7 computer, I completely installed Kali Linux to my computer which deleted all my Windows 7 because I didn't need it. Now Kali Linux is installed on my hard disk on all partitions. I have used it for a while, and now I want to uninstall it completely and reinstall Windows 7.

Now I inserted the Windows 7 disk and tried to install it, but it shows an error that Windows cannot be installed in this partition. I know Kali Linux formatted all my partitions to ext4 which is its own default format, but Windows can be installed to NTFS format, but the Windows installation doesn't give me an option for formatting, so I am stuck here. Please help me find a solution. Remember that Linux and Windows here are not in dual boot.

Comment: I wanted to add here is that THERE IS NO OPTION FOR ME TO FORMAT in the windows 7 installation. I know there is an option but the options listed here are only Refresh and Load drivers and NOT the Advsnced option. Is there some way that I can do the formatting on Kali Linux??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer - before doing anything with partitions, make sure you have good backups**

In Windows setup, during the part where you select which partition, select the advanced option, then just delete all the partitions.

You do not have to create **any** paritions, Windows setup will do that for you.  All you need is a blank drive.  (Unless you have some special requirements for partitioning, like saving some space for a Linux partition).

[image]

Comment: thanks but I told it already that there is no option to format the drive

Comment: You need to delete existing partitions first.

Comment: But how from where

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: Step 5 onward from here: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/52291-partition-hard-drive-windows-7-install.html

Comment: Ok david thanks for everything now I have realized my carelessness

Comment: @UsmanZiaMalik if my solution solved you problem, could you mark it as the accepted solution thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to remove all partitions, create a new one and then format it to NTFS. You can do this from the windows 7 setup.

Note, removing a partition will delete its data entirely, not just windows, but all other files as well. Be sure to make proper backups.

Comment: It should be sufficient to delete the existing partitions and then boot using the Windows disk. You'll be able to create the necessary partitions for Windows during the installation procedure. You aren't saying otherwise, just trying to clarify this point.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton thanks for the addition. Yeah removing the partition can both be done during the setup and from linux itself.

Comment: Ok but I cant format anything from the windows 7 setup is there any way I can do that IN KALI LINUX?

Comment: Please tell me a way to do the formatting and uninstalling of kali linux

Comment: @UsmanZiaMalik First you need to remove the partition. From selecting the partition, choose delete. If no partitions show up, you'll have to do this from linux itself. Given that doing this is different per distro, and I only worked with opensuse, I can't tell you how to do it through kali linux.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from kali or any other Linux distribution DVD and boot in live mode.

Open Gparted.

Format the drive or resize it and change the format from ext4 to NTFS

Now,  you can finally install Windows on that partition you resized or formatted.